# Differentiate a function with trigonometric exponent

Tags: calculus, logarithms, implicit-differentiation

$y = -3^{\sin(x)} - 3^x$
or
$y = -[3^{\sin(x)} + 3^x]$.
The problem I'm facing is that if I take negative sign out of parentheses and then differentiate it, it's easy, but if I try to differentiate it with the negative sign associated with both terms, then, let's take just $-3^{\sin(x)}$, this happens

$$ \ln y = \sin(x)\ln(-3) $$

This term has $\ln(+3)$ if I don't take negative out of parentheses. Are both ways correct? Is there some kind of identity that can  change $\ln(-3)$ to $\ln(3)$ cause I'm sure I can't simply  take the sign outside.

Comment: $(-3)^{\sin{x}} \neq -3^{\sin{x}}$

Comment: we have $$(a^x)'=a^x\ln(a)$$

Comment: Please clarify phrases such as "if I take - common" and "with the -ve sign".  Also avoid colloquialisms such as "cuz" and fix your grammar and punctuation.  Otherwise we won't think you're serious about your mathematical question.

Comment: Chappers can u please explain that a bit?

Comment: @David G. Stork so if a person is unable to express himself clearly then he's not being serious? Eng (same as  English, just abbreviated) is not  my native language. Please report my question as troll behaviour or whatever because I totally agree with you and whoever comes up with such great community guidelines

Comment: @PizzaThug "unable" is much different that "unwilling".  If you're writing "-ve", then clearly you are aware of the word "negative".  And yes: if a person is not *willing* to *try* to express themselves clearly, then that person is not being serious, by the standards of this site.

Comment: I agree with @Omnomnomnom that the issue is the *unwillingness* to respect the expertise and work of potential solvers/helpers who donate their time and expertise.  I was a professor of math for several years and never heard of "-ve" as some texting version of "negative."  (I still have no idea what "I take - common" means.)  This surely has nothing whatsoever to do with being a non-native English speaker.  I frequently and generously edit non-negative English speaker's writing, as you can see by scrolling through hundreds of questions.  But they are generally *trying*.  You were not.

Comment: (....non-*native* English...)

Comment: @David G. Stork actually I was about to apologise immediately after I wrote that reply sir. Im sorry for my immature behaviour.I didn't mean to disrespect experts on the site in any way through the manner in which I wrote my question. Sorry again sir I'll try to be more expressive in the future

Comment: @Pizza Thug.  Thank you.  We honestly try to help... especially those new to the site.  (I see your reputation is a beginner's 18.)  If you do the work, try to ask clear, good questions, and (to your ability) help others, you'll find this an extremely valuable site, you'll have your questions answered, and the mathematics will advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the derivative of $g(x)=-f_1(x)-f_2(x)$ is
$$
g'(x)=-f_1'(x)-f_2'(x)
$$
(provided both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are differentiable), you just need to compute the derivatives of
$$
f_1(x)=3^{\sin x}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
f_2(x)=3^x
$$
Here you can use the logarithmic derivative:
$$
\ln f_1(x)=\sin x\ln 3
$$
so
$$
\frac{f_1'(x)}{f_1(x)}=\cos x\ln 3
$$
and finally
$$
f_1'(x)=3^{\sin x}\cos x\ln 3
$$
The derivative of $f_2$ is $f_2'(x)=3^x\ln 3$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you kind sir

Comment: @PizzaThug *Divide et impera*

Answer (score 0):

after my hint above the derivative is given by $$-{3}^{\sin \left( x \right) }\cos \left( x \right) \ln  \left( 3
 \right) -{3}^{x}\ln  \left( 3 \right) 
$$